# How to redirect into another html login page using ng-include and ng-click events?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I am new to AngularJs. I have 2 different html pages. I have created a website which have static home page and login page which will access through button. How to load login page using ng-include and ng-click? Other solutions are also appreciated.

Comment: Please share some code which you tried and where you are facing difficulty in achieving the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on ng-click event, do something like this to go next html page.

```
$scope.GoToNextPage = function (Id) {
window.open('/Serials/Serials?Id=' + Id,'');}
```

here Id is used for getting data against Id number